# increase length of sku in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sku

We use magento 2.2.2 and we need a longer SKU.
We set "const SKU_MAX_LENGTH = 255;" 
in the file module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Sku.php
but it does not work

Comment: You also need to increase it in database

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change field size at the database table.

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity` CHANGE `sku` `sku` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU';
```

Comment: If we run setup:upgrade, It changes this field to VARCHAR(64) again.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the into database as well.
Goto table **eav_attribute**, search for **sku** at column attribute code then edit the resulted row.

Update the field **frontend_class** to **null** or **validate-length maximum-length-255** according to your requirement.

Now check the admin it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can install this module it will increase sku length upto 255
 https://github.com/Mehran515/Increase-Sku-Length

Comment: Please disclose affiliation when linking to your own content.

Comment: what how do i disclose affiliation?

Comment: A simple "This is my repository" or something to that effect will do.